# QAPage with multiple questions

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

Is it possible to list multiple questions in the question markup and link them to one `QAPage`?

When I try the following JSON-LD, the Google test tool responds with the error that there is only one question allowed:

> Exactly one `Question` expected on page for `QAPage`.

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "QAPage",
"@id": "QAPage1",
    "description":"Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla.",
    "image":"https://www.example.com/images/blabla.jpg",
    "name":"Blabla Blabla.",
    "url":"https://www.example.com"

}
</script>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
 "@graph": [
{
"@type": "Question",
"@id": "Question1",
"name": "Is this question 1?",
"upvoteCount": "196",
"text": "Is this question 1?",
"dateCreated": "2010-11-04T20:07Z",
"author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "someuser"
},
"answerCount": "4",
"acceptedAnswer": {
    "@type": "Answer",
    "upvoteCount": "1337",
    "url": "https://www.example.com",
    "text": "(The text of the accepted answer goes here...).",
    "dateCreated": "2010-12-01T22:01Z",
    "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "someuser"
    }
},
"suggestedAnswer": {
    "@type": "Answer",
    "upvoteCount": "39",
    "url": "https://www.example.com",
    "text": "(The text of the accepted answer goes here...).",
    "dateCreated": "2010-12-06T21:11Z",
    "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "lonelyuser1234"
    }
},
"mainEntityOfPage": "QAPage1"
},
{
"@type": "Question",
"@id": "Question2",
"name": "Is this question 2?",
"upvoteCount": "196",
"text": "Is this question 2?",
"dateCreated": "2010-11-04T20:07Z",
"author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "someuser"
},
"answerCount": "4",
"acceptedAnswer": {
    "@type": "Answer",
    "upvoteCount": "1337",
    "url": "https://www.example.com",
    "text": "(The text of the accepted answer goes here...).",
    "dateCreated": "2010-12-01T22:01Z",
    "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "someuser"
    }
},
"suggestedAnswer": {
    "@type": "Answer",
    "upvoteCount": "39",
    "url": "https://www.example.com",
    "text": "(The text of the accepted answer goes here...).",
    "dateCreated": "2010-12-06T21:11Z",
    "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "lonelyuser1234"
    }
},
"mainEntityOfPage": "QAPage1"
}
]
}
</script>
```

I think it makes sense to allow more than one question per page. In my case it is a FAQ page where are several questions an answers. Is there anyone who has solved that problem?

Answer (score 3):

The description of the [`QAPage`](https://schema.org/QAPage) type:

> A QAPage is a WebPage focussed on a specific Question and its Answer(s), e.g. in a question answering site or documenting Frequently Asked Questions (FAQs).

So it’s for *one* question. If you have multiple questions on the same page, you shouldn’t use `QAPage`.

There is a [`FAQPage`](https://schema.org/FAQPage) type, but [it’s currently in Pending](https://pending.schema.org/FAQPage) (so it’s subject to change, see [discussion about it](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/1723)), which currently has this description:

> A FAQPage is a WebPage presenting one or more "Frequently asked questions" (see also QAPage).

It could look like:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "FAQPage",
  "hasPart": [
    {"@type": "Question"},
    {"@type": "Question"},
    {"@type": "Question"}
  ]
}
```

If your page has multiple questions, but not *frequently asked* questions (so it’s not a typical FAQ page), you shouldn’t use `QAPage` nor `FAQPage`. Go with their parent type, [`WebPage`](https://schema.org/WebPage) (or its subtype [`CollectionPage`](https://schema.org/CollectionPage)), instead.

Comment: Doesn't the "or documenting Frequently Asked Questions (FAQs)." imply multiple Questions?

Comment: @Mattypants: I think this example is referring to a FAQ section in which each FAQ has its own page. Otherwise it wouldn’t make sense that "Question" is singular while "Answer(s)" is singular and plural. --- If `FAQPage` gets into Core, this example will likely be removed from the `QAPage` description.